# Java hibernate-validator @interface load from properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, interface, hibernate-validator

I saw following hibernate validator code

```
package org.hibernate.validator.constraints;
...
public @interface CreditCardNumber {
   String message() default "{org.hibernate.validator.constraints.CreditCardNumber.message}";
...
}
```

and in the properties files has key value the credit card error message like

```
org.hibernate.validator.constraints.CreditCardNumber.message        = invalid credit card number
```

how do hibernate validator do such things
i mean load properties on @interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doc: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.developing-auto-configuration

#1. create the autoconfig class

```
@AutoConfiguration
public class ObiValidatorAutoConfiguration {

    private MessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("classpath:messages");
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalValidatorFactoryBean getValidator() {
        LocalValidatorFactoryBean bean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        bean.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource());
        return bean;
    }
}
```

#2. Locating Auto-configuration Candidates
create file `META-INF/spring/org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration.imports`
with content like
`package.location.ObiValidatorAutoConfiguration`

#3. create the default error message file (for ex: `resources/messages.properties`)
with content
`package.cc.message=contains invalid character`

#4. the annotation class

```
@Pattern(regexp = "[\\.a-zA-Z0-9]*")
@Target({ FIELD, PARAMETER })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = {})
@ReportAsSingleViolation
public @interface CreditCard {
    String message() default "{package.cc.message}";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

#5. use that annotation on spring-boot app, and when value is not valid then the default value (`contains invalid character`) is show up

Answer (score 0):

Edit: **Since I completely overlooked that it was about annotations, this answer does not apply to this question.**

As explained here [Java Properties file examples](https://mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/) you could use [Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) class in your interface, with the method's default implementation as you already began.

```java
public interface CreditCardNumber {
    Properties properties = new Properties();

    default String message() throws IOException {
        properties.load(Main.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties"));
        return properties.getProperty("org.hibernate.validator.constraints.CreditCardNumber.message");
    };
}
```

Or even a neater solution would be to create your own custom(a wrapper solution would be fine) Properties class, where you would load the properties file in its constructor (during construction). So you don't have to call `properties.load(...)` whenever you need it.

Comment: we can't have method body under interface class

Answer (score 0):

To be clear - Hibernate Validator does not load the properties into an annotation. The annotation only references the key from the property file. Getting values out is part of [interpolating constraint error messages](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/6.2/reference/en-US/html_single/#chapter-message-interpolation). This process is a bit more complex than just reading a file, it has to deal with internationalization and interpolation.

As for the actual reading of the property files, in this case, it's done through `ResourceBundle`s that underneath is using `Properties` class to load the data.

Comment: i'm sorry i might bothering you, but hibernate validator has lot of file and many things that i don't understand

i just want to create custom annotation like @CreditCardNumber with default error message from properties file and use that annotation in springboot controller

can you help me where should i start please